# Creating Google Firebase admin for developer use

Tags: firebase

I would like to assign myself as an admin to a client's Google Firebase account. I am creating a small website and need need access to his Google Firebase. Thus far, I have been using his UN and PW to login to his account.

Is there any way to assign myself as an admin on his Google Firebase account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add collaborators to your Firebase project, from the [Users and Permissions](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/iam) panel in the Firebase console. Here's an example from a project I'm working on:

[image]

Each user has a role in there, which controls precisely what they're allowed to do. The <kbd>Owner</kbd> is one of the broadest roles, and means the user has full access to the project.